# Using emacs for learning python with numpy

Tags: python

I would like to use `emacs` for learning `python` with `numpy`.  How can I proceed ? Have seen other using `Jupyter` but would prefer using emacs instead.

Would it be possible to have a simple example using `numpy` that I can execute from emacs ?

Comment: [Here](https://martibosch.github.io/jupyter-emacs-universe/) you can find a nice blog article about using Emacs as Jupyter notebook alternative. I would recommend using org-mode, as the 'IDE' functionality can be fixed (I will probably write more about that somewhere soon)

Comment: Would look forward to read about it.

Comment: Would you provide an `org-mode` example that uses operations from `numpy` that I can run ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Org mode has the best support in emacs. You will need [Babel](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html) to create and execute snippets of python code that will print the results on the subsequent lines. Images can be displayed as well, but need to be saved to a file first (it's minor inconvenience, but it provides greater portability). This route will be more challenging initially than something like jupyter notebook, but you will be able to use git to version control your "notebooks" (.org files), because at the end of the day org mode file is just a plain text file (as opposed to large json documents saved as .ipynb).

You theoretically could run jupyter notebooks in emacs, as well with packages like ein or emacs-jupyter, but it won't be a pleasant experience (I've tried only ein, not sure what emacs-jupyter is like).

Python examples: https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-python.html

Comment: Right.  Did `ein` and `emacs-jupyter` but did not see them becoming valuable tools for many programmers.